# Sub links invisible in quick-launch menu of a custom master page

Tags: 2013, quick-launch

I am using a Quick-launch menu with structural navigation in SharePoint 2013.
Sublinks are visible in the Seattle master page but they 
don't show up in my master page.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see I had to increase StaticDisplayLevels value to more than 1.

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" StaticDisplayLevels="3"
```